# How to Deploy to a Linux VM from Window system using Ansible

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I have requirement to deploy my application in Linux platform.Currently my Jenkins and nexus are running in windows platform.Is it possible to achieve this using Ansible.I have added Ansible plugin in my Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Ansible cannot run on a Windows host and can only manage Windows hosts. But there is the solution using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) but not really recommended.

I'm wondering about you Jenkins slaves, one of the slaves can be a Linux based one and you can trigger ansible from there.